Prevent Uno BrowserEmbed mode from messing up HTML
When using BrowserEmbeded mode Uno generates embdeded.js that loads the WASM. But the generated code contains unrequired HTML elements:
const html = "<div id='uno-body' class='container-fluid uno-body'><div class='uno-loader' loading-position='bottom' loading-alert='none'><img class='logo' src='' /><progress></progress><span class='alert'></span></div></div>";

    if(typeof unoRootElement !== 'undefined') {
        unoRootElement.innerHTML = html;
    } else {
        var rootDiv = document.createElement("div");
        rootDiv.innerHTML = html;
        document.body.appendChild(rootDiv);
    }

    const loadScript = s => new Promise((ok, err) => {
        const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
        scriptElement.setAttribute("src", `${absolutePath}/${s}.js`);
        scriptElement.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        scriptElement.onload = () => ok();
        scriptElement.onerror = () => err("err loading " + s);
        document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
    });

    // Preload RequireJS dependency
    await loadScript("require");

    // Launch the bootstrapper
    await import(absolutePath + "/uno-bootstrap.js");

Is there some way to prevent any HTML element generation? I just want to load the bootstrap JS.
